# data.table | merge data on a rolling basis

Tags: r, date, data.table

I have two datasets similar to the following sample data:

```
set.seed(1)

id_all = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2)

dta1 = data.table()
dta1[, id := id_all]
dta1[, date := sample(seq(as.Date('1999/01/01'), as.Date('2000/01/01'), by="day"), 5)]
dta1[, value := sample(seq(1, 10, 1), 5)]

dta2 = data.table()
dta2[, id := id_all]
dta2[, date := sample(seq(as.Date('1999/01/01'), as.Date('2000/01/01'), by="day"), 5)]
```

```
> setorder(dta1, id, date); dta1
   id      date  value
1:  1 1999-05-09     1
2:  1 1999-06-16     3
3:  1 1999-11-20     2
4:  2 1999-09-27     7
5:  2 1999-10-26     5
```

```
> setorder(dta2, id, date); dta2
   id      date
1:  1 1999-09-20
2:  1 1999-11-26
3:  1 1999-12-28
4:  2 1999-03-20
5:  2 1999-11-25
```

I'd like to merge the two dataset based on `id` and `date`,  in a way that `value` of `dta1` are matched to the closest **later** `date` of `dta2`. As such, the merged data should be like this:

```
   id     date.x     date.y  value
1:  1 1999-09-20 1999-06-16     3
2:  1 1999-11-26 1999-11-20     2
3:  1 1999-12-28 1999-11-20     2
4:  2 1999-03-20
5:  2 1999-11-25 1999-10-26     5
```

Any suggestions? Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: I think this is a rolling join.  See the data.table-package documentation.

Comment: `dta1[dta2, on=.(id,date), roll=+Inf]`

Comment: Thanks, all. I though a rolling join finds the closest date, not a "later" date. Sorry for a dumb question.